# wso2 setting up the database mysql

Tags: mysql, database, wso2, wso2-esb

I tried setting up the database in my wso2 ESB by following this documentation from wso2 https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Setting+up+MySQL
but the sql file returned an error when I tried importing it to a database by using the command 'source dbscripts/mysql.sql'. I am using the latest version of WSO2ESB which is the 5.0.0 BETA2

Here's my mysql error

```
ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'REG_CREATED_TIME'
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'regdb.reg_resource' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'regdb.reg_resource' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'regdb.reg_resource' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'regdb.reg_resource' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'regdb.reg_resource' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'regdb.reg_resource' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'regdb.reg_resource' doesn't exist
ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'REG_LAST_UPDATED_TIME'
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'regdb.reg_resource_history' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'regdb.reg_resource_history' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'regdb.reg_resource_history' doesn't exist
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'regdb.reg_resource' doesn't exist
```

Here's the log http://pastebin.com/N9C4gyGX

Comment: What is the ESB version that you are trying?

Comment: I am using the latest version which is ESB 5.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest WSO2 ESB is released now, can you try with the Released pack located at http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/

Also if you are using MYSQL 5.7 you should be running the mysql5.7.sql script located at dbscripts directory.

Comment: Also rather than sourcing the sql scripts manually you can use the -Dsetup flag to Automatically create the necessary tables. e.g : sh wso2server.sh -Dsetup

Comment: Lets try using the latest pack, Also make sure that you use fresh databases. Its possible that DB is corrupted. If you still get this issue, share your master-datasources.xml configs.

Comment: What is the MQSQL version you are using?

Comment: It seems you are using MYSQL version 5.7. If that's the case there is a separate script just for mysql 5.7 and u can find this script at  dbscripts directory. You can try executing this  script.

Comment: I got that reg resource error removed but it triggered a new one. http://pastebin.com/kDr0yEBY

Comment: Execute the SQL script without the -Dsetup option. This will reveal any SQL errors and do share the logs.

Comment: Sorry, What I wanted to say is, source the MYSQL script directly, without the ESB.

Comment: You also need to execute the script in dbscripts directory as well as scripts in dbscripts/identity.

Comment: So I have to execute both mysql.sql and mysql-5.7+.sql? if so which one should go first?

Comment: Well I tried executing both and the `reg_resource doesnt` exist came back.

Comment: No there are two different scripts. dbscripts/mysql5.7.sql. Drop all the existing tables and try executing this fist. Then you can execute dbscripts/identity/mysql-5.7+.sql

Comment: I didn't notice that... it's all working now. Thanks! but I am getting this warning.  http://pastebin.com/uuS1rRai

Comment: This exception is thrown by the driver it self. You can enable SSL in MySQL to overcome this. This is actually harmless if the setup is a non production setup. When you move into production enabling SSL in MySQL is recommended.